# how to overlay an element above a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do you overlay an element above a container? I already tried setting the z-index to -1 but that didn't work. I am trying to make my line `vh1` appear over my container but it's not working. My current code is attached below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
    .con-2{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
}

.row-3{
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 75%;
}

.col-6{
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    width: 55%;
    background-color: aqua;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 14%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.vh1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 0.5%;
    background-color: aqua;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px aqua;
    height: 2.5px;
    width: calc(5% - 20px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scanner-h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: scanner-horizontal-loop 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

@keyframes scanner-horizontal-loop {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
    }

    50% {
        left: 0;
    }

    100% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid con-2">
        <div class="row row-3">
            <div class="col col-6">
                <div class="card card-1" onclick="myfunction()" ondblclick="stopListen()">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/microphone--v2.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="vh1">
                    <div class="scanner-h1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-2" onclick="myfunction()">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/search--v2.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `vh1` is already above `con-2`! Plz explain properly what you want.

Comment: vh1 was not above con-2. But I just figured out what the problem was. Answer is below.@ManasKhandelwal

Comment: Below? Where?..

Comment: just added it actually you are right It was there just was to small to see. @ManasKhandelwal

Answer (score 0):

In the css vh1 has a width set to cal(5%-20px); the width was set with respect to the whole body not con-2. Changed it to cal(100%-20px); and it worked.